# Condition 'if' not working with .load()

Tags: javascript, php

I'm new here and I ask for your understanding
I am downloading from the script :

```
echo '<div id="xx">';
if ($nazwa == "1234") {
    $nazwa_color = "red";
} else {
    $nazwa_color = "black";
}

echo '<div style="padding-left:0px;float:left;margin-left:1px;"><input type="text"  autocomplete="off"
    style="font-family:Tahoma;text-indent:2px;text-align:left;font-size:12px;width:500px;height:29px;background-color : White ; color : ' . $nazwa_color . ';border-width:1px;border-style:ridge;border-color:rgb(208,208,208);"
     name="nazwa" value="b" class="wyk_edit"></div>';
echo'</div>';
```

And in javascript :

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".xx").load("setup-wyklady/wyk_edit_proces.php #xx");
```

does not address the condition 'if'. Why?

Thanks, but not working. Maybe I show all.
This is the portion of the file that you want to replace the method of load:

```
$wyk_query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nazwy_wyklady WHERE id_wykladu <> 9999 ORDER BY nr") or die('Błąd zapytania');       
while($wyk=mysql_fetch_array($wyk_query1)){    //begin loop

        $id_wykladu=$wyk['id_wykladu'] ;
        $nr=$wyk['nr'] ;
        $nazwa=$wyk['nazwa'] ;
     echo '<form action="../wyklady/setup-wyklady/wyk_edit_proces.php" method="post"> ';
   echo '<div style="float:left;width:590px;margin-top:2px;background:none" >'; 
      echo '<div style="padding-left:0px;float:left;margin-left:1px;"><input type="text"  readonly="readonly"
    style="font-family:Tahoma;text-indent:2px;text-align:center;font-size:12px;width:30px;height:29px;background-color : White ; color : black;border-width:1px;border-style:ridge;border-color:rgb(208,208,208);"
     name="nr" value="'.$nr.'" class="wyk_edit_nr"></div>';
       if($nazwa=="1234")
     {  
     $nazwa_color = "red" ;
     }
     else
     {
     $nazwa_color = "black" ;
     }
           echo '<div style="padding-left:0px;float:left;margin-left:1px;" class="xx"><input type="text"  autocomplete="off"
    style="font-family:Tahoma;text-indent:2px;text-align:left;font-size:12px;width:500px;height:29px;background-color : White ; color : '.$nazwa_color.';border-width:1px;border-style:ridge;border-color:rgb(208,208,208);"
     name="nazwa" value="'.$nazwa.'" class="wyk_edit"></div>';
      echo '<div style="float:left;margin-left:15px;margin-top:1px;" >
 <input  style="display:none;cursor:pointer;width:25px;height:25px;background-color:White;color:rgb(193,135,107);" id="edit_button" title="zatwierdź zmiany" value="" class="wyk_edit_button"></div>' ;
       echo '<input type="hidden" name="id_wykladu" value="'.$id_wykladu.' " class="wyk_edit_id">  ';

          echo '</div>';   // 2a
               echo '</form> '; 
                     }     //end of loop
```

and a script that loads (wyk_edit_proces.php):

```
$wyk_query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nazwy_wyklady WHERE id_wykladu ='$id_wykladu1'") or die('Błąd zapytania');
    $wyk=mysql_fetch_array($wyk_query1) ;
        $id_wykladu=$wyk['id_wykladu'] ;
        $nr=$wyk['nr'] ;
        $nazwa=$wyk['nazwa'] ;
      echo '<form action="../wyklady/setup-wyklady/wyk_edit_proces.php" method="post"> ';
   echo '<div style="float:left;width:590px;margin-top:2px;background:none" >';   

     echo '<div style="padding-left:0px;float:left;margin-left:1px;"><input type="text"  readonly="readonly"
    style="font-family:Tahoma;text-indent:2px;text-align:center;font-size:12px;width:30px;height:29px;background-color : White ; color : black;border-width:1px;border-style:ridge;border-color:rgb(208,208,208);"
     name="nr" value="'.$nr1.'" class="wyk_edit_nr"></div>';
         if($nazwa=="1234")
     {  
     $nazwa_color = "red" ;
     }
     else
     {
     $nazwa_color = "black" ;
     }

       echo '<div style="padding-left:0px;float:left;margin-left:1px;"><input type="text"  autocomplete="off"
    style="font-family:Tahoma;text-indent:2px;text-align:left;font-size:12px;width:500px;height:29px;background-color : White ; color : '.$nazwa_color.';border-width:1px;border-style:ridge;border-color:rgb(208,208,208);"
     name="nazwa" value="b" class="wyk_edit"></div>';

  echo '<div style="float:left;margin-left:15px;margin-top:1px;" >
 <input  style="display:none;cursor:pointer;width:25px;height:25px;background-color:White;color:rgb(193,135,107);" id="edit_button" title="zatwierdź zmiany" value="" class="wyk_edit_button"></div>' ;


      echo '<input type="hidden" name="id_wykladu" value="'.$id_wykladu.' " class="wyk_edit_id">  ';



          echo '</div>';   

          echo '</form> ';
```

and javascript:

```
<script> 
      //-----------------------------------------------------------------ajax - wykłady
    $(document).ready(function(){



        $(".wyk_edit_button").click(function () {

         var id_wykladu1 =  $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".wyk_edit_id").val();
         var nr1 =  $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".wyk_edit_nr").val();
         var nazwa1 =  $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".wyk_edit").val().trim();     
        // alert(id_wykladu1 + " " + nr1 + " " + nazwa1)
        if(nazwa1 == "")
        {
          alert("puste");
        }
        else
          {
           $.ajax({
    type     : "POST",
    url      : "setup-wyklady/wyk_edit_proces.php",
    data     : {
            id_wykladu : id_wykladu1,
            nr : nr1,
            nazwa : nazwa1
    },
    context: this,

    success : function() { 

   $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".wyk_edit").load("setup-wyklady/wyk_edit_proces.php", function(){
   alert("Done");
   });   


             if (!$(".popup:visible").length) {
            $(".popup").fadeIn(1);
        }   

    },
    complete : function(r) { 

    },
    error:    function(error) {

    }
});  

             }  

                 });

    $(".popup .bg, .popup .container").click(function() {
        $(".popup").fadeOut(250);


    });

            });
</script>
```

What you think about async:false ?

Comment: Please check this out http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you are talking about the php if condition, what is `$nazwa`? How are you setting it?

Comment: even seems to me problems in quotes also there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the jQuery .load-Method works asynchronus as mentioned in [this](http://api.jquery.com/load/) article. Try to use the invoked callback-function:

```
$(randomstuff).load("test",function()
{
    alert("I'm done");
}
```